# How to remove language parameter from url in google webmaster tools

Tags: google-search-console

There is a section named "[URL parameters](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1235687?hl=en)" for dealing changes in URL structure, recently I remove language code from URL, how can I notify google about that?

http://www.tarafdari.com/fa/node/26987
changed to 
http://www.tarafdari.com/node/26987

Answer (score 2):

The URL Parameters section of Webmaster Tools cannot do what you want it to do.

URL parameters are name value pairs that come after the question mark.  For example in the URL `http://example.com/folder/page.html?sessionid=738392930320` the parameter name is `sessionid` and you could tell Google to crawl "one representative URL" because each visitor gets a different number.

Webmaster tools provides no functionality for having Googlebot ignore other parts of the URL.  You will need to find a different method to have Googlebot crawl your content correctly.  You could try 301 redirects or a canonical meta tag.